# Export (a function) from the entry, using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I would like to export from the `entry`:

**C.js**:

```
export default class C { static get foo() { return "foo"; } }
```

**entry.js**:

```
import C from "./C";
export default function callMe(a) { return a + C.foo; }
```

This (using `libraryTarget: "amd"`) would result in something like *(simplified)*

**output.js**:

```
define("entry", ["./C"], function(C) { return function(a) { return a + C.foo; }; })
```

However, when `webpack`ing the `entry`, I get an output that just exports `{}`, even though it correctly contains `callMe`.

Comment: For some reason it works with `libraryTarget: "umd"`, maybe PEBKAC

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `libraryTarget: "umd"`